# Solve second order linear differential equation with two variables.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$ax_1(t)''=k(x_2(t)-x_1(t)), $

$bx_2(t)''=-k(x_2(t)-x_1(t))$

where $a,b,k$ were some none $0$ constant.

How to solve the above equation with:

(1) variation of parameters.

(2) the system of differential equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Solve the First equation for $x_2$ and plug it into the second equation. To obtain a scalar ODE, solve with Euler’s exponential ansatz.

In order to solve it as a system you will need to introduce intermediate variables $x_1’=x_0$ and $x_2’=x_3$. Then determine the system matrix and its eigenvalues and eigenvectors.